# Python/MySQL ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'

Tags: python, mysql

my program sends me the following error message after executing the function to insert in the database:

```
Traceback:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python33\Archive\MySQL-teste12.py", line 275, in <module>
    inserir(cursor, cx2)
  File "C:\Python33\Archive\MySQL-teste12.py", line 193, in inserir
    cursor.execute(add_produto)
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\cursor.py", line 415, in execute
    self._handle_result(self._connection.cmd_query(stmt))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 593, in cmd_query
    result = self._handle_result(self._send_cmd(ServerCmd.QUERY, query))
  File "C:\Python33\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\connection.py", line 515, in _handle_result
    raise errors.get_exception(packet)
mysql.connector.errors.ProgrammingError: 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'd' in 'field list'`
```

The following table is trying to being inserted:

```
produto = """
     CREATE TABLE produto (
     prod_nu int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
     nome varchar(30) NOT NULL,
     data_lcm date NOT NULL,
     preco int(11) NOT NULL,
     PRIMARY KEY (prod_nu)
     ) ENGINE=InnoDB
     """
```

Here is the procedure where the error occur. I believe it's not accepting any format of date. I've tried many variations, and none of them worked:

```
def inserir (cursor, db):
    # excess code removed                
    vb = input('Digite a data de Lançamento do Produto (Ano/mês/dia).')
    now = time.strftime('vb')
    …
    add_produto = ("""INSERT INTO produto(nome,
                      data_lcm, preco)
                      VALUES (%s, %s, %s)""" % (va,vb,vc))

    cursor.execute(add_produto)
            …
```

Comment: Please try to include only the relevant code in your question. It makes it easier to see what is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two problems, the first is that you are never creating a `date` object. Given your instructions (Ano/mês/dia) this would be something like

```
input_date = datetime.strptime(input_string, '%Y/%m/%d')
```

The second problem is that

```
now = time.strftime('vb')
```

sets `now` to `'vb'` because it has no strftime directives in it. If you are looking for a standard time format, it is hard to go wrong with [date.isoformat()](http://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.date.isoformat) which would make

```
now = input_date.isoformat()
```

Comment: Also don't forget the parsing of queries instead of passing in values as parameters (`% (va,vb,vc)`)